# Symfony dropdown from array

Tags: php, symfony

I have symfony form with field

```
        ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                'Developer' => 'ROLE_DEVELOPER',
                'Support' => 'ROLE_SUPPORT',
                'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN'
            ],
            'multiple' => true,
        ]);
```

And I want to remove multiple option, but symfony fall down with exception

`phpfpm_1       | NOTICE: PHP message: [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: "Notice: Array to string conversion" at /var/www/symfony/vendor/symfony/form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php line 68`

How to avoid it?

Comment: Please share more details. This works as long as `multiple => true` is given, but after removing that line, it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the database the roles field is defined as array so the choice type must return a value of type array.
to resolve this issue u should use Data Transformers (convert array to string).
check this:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html